# What will happen after updating price in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Imagine I have a plan with price of $x yearly. and there are lots of subscribed users on it. what will happen if I update the plan's price to $y? all users subscription will remain unchanged and they will pay $x for the future invoices or they will pay new price ($y) for upcoming invoice?

Comment: You **can't** update a Plan's price in Stripe, it's immutable by design.(exactly because of potential complications like this one). You would create a new plan instead and move each customer to it explicitly : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing

Comment: @karllekko you mean I have to change swap subscription price for each customer manually ? and are users aware of this change?

Comment: yes you'd swap manually, and it's up to you how to notify them or if they're charged a prorated amount and so on, you control that as part of your payments integration.